# Export non-Camera Roll Photo Albums to PC?

Tags: iphone, photos, pc

Is there any way to export non Camera Roll or Photo Stream photo albums from an iPhone to a PC? There are a bunch of "free" software online than can do this, but they all require you to buy the software to transfer the photos, or they can only transfer a few photos before needing to buy the software.

The iPhone is hooked up to the computer right now and I can browse the DCIM folder, but those are only Camera Roll pictures. I'm not willing to jailbreak the iPhone either as it's not mine.

Comment: What photos are you trying to transfer that are not in the Camera Roll or Photo Stream?

Comment: I think they're photos that were transferred from another iPhone, but now the user wants to export those and I can't seem to find a way to do it. Those albums aren't on his computer either.

Comment: Photos transferred from an iPhone go into the Camera Roll. Are you referring to photos synced through iTunes?

Comment: Probably. The description beneath the album title is "49 from My Computer." Does that mean they were synced through iTunes?

Comment: Yes, that means it was synchronised to the device. Thanks for the clarifications. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only transfer photos out of a device that were taken on the device or are otherwise in the Camera Roll. Photos synchronised to a device over iTunes are not able to be synchronised in reverse or otherwise taken *from* a device.

Comment: All right, so those photos are essentially lost forever unless  the user emails them bit by bit to themselves? Would an app like Dropbox and its Camera Upload feature be able to get those photos off of the device?

Comment: @Catalog I don't think Dropbox would be able to access the photos as they are not shown in public APIs as far as I'm aware, but I might be wrong as I haven't read through such APIs for any recent version of iOS. Email is certainly an option, along with AirDrop if you have another iOS device (or OS X Yosemite when it's released), or Flickr.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way is using AirDrop. You have to select every photo manually but you can extract them without special software.